# How to dynamically assign a controller in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a lot of different types that I would like to retrieve using controllers, but it's not practical to create a controller for each one. In ASP.NET 4.8 I used an entity controller selector class which implemented the `IHttpControllerSelector` interface, but there isn't an equivalent for that in .NET Core.

I wrote a custom middleware that iterates through a collection of `EntitySetConfiguration` and gets the controller type as follows:

```
IEnumerable<EntitySetConfiguration>
```

```
if (_entitySets != null)
{
    foreach (var set in _entitySets)
    {
        var entityType = set.ClrType;
        var controllerType = typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
        // context.Items["controllerType"] = controllerType;
        var route = $"/{set.Name}/{entityType.Name}";
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that if the route is `/MyCustomType` a `GenericController<MyCustomType>` gets created and routed?

This is for a custom OData REST API. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Never used this, but I think [MapDynamicControllerRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapdynamiccontrollerroute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) may help. Here is blog post about the feature: https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/

Comment: Also check the [IControllerModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-8.0). https://medium.com/@ajays871/generic-rest-controller-and-generic-entity-framework-implementation-in-asp-net-core-application-a91b18507b55

Answer (score 1):

You could try below possible way to achieve dynamic controller requirement.

For that first you have to create `GenericController<T>`:

```
public class GenericController<T> : ControllerBase where T : class
{
    // Implement your controller actions
}
```

Define a middleware:

```
 public class EntityRoutingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
        public EntityRoutingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IEnumerable<EntitySetConfiguration> entitySets)
{
    var path = context.Request.Path.Value.Trim('/');
    var routeValuesFeature = context.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>();

    if (routeValuesFeature == null)
    {
        routeValuesFeature = new RouteValuesFeature();
        context.Features.Set<IRouteValuesFeature>(routeValuesFeature);
    }

    var routeValues = routeValuesFeature.RouteValues;

    foreach (var set in entitySets)
    {
        if (path.Equals(set.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var entityType = set.ClrType;
            var controllerName = $"Generic{entityType.Name}";
            routeValues["controller"] = controllerName;
            routeValues["action"] = "YourActionMethod"; // Adjust this to your actual action method
            break;
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}

    }
```

Register the middleware in `Startup.Configure`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ....

    // Add your custom middleware before UseRouting()
    app.UseMiddleware<EntityRoutingMiddleware>(/* pass your EntitySetConfiguration collection here */);

    app.UseRouting();
    ......
    .......
}
```

Register the generic controller type in your `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add application services.
    services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices()
        .PartManager.FeatureProviders.Add(new GenericControllerFeatureProvider());
}

public class GenericControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            var controllerType = typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(entityType).GetTypeInfo();
            feature.Controllers.Add(controllerType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue where SetRouteData(routeData) doesn't exist on context. There's GetRouteData, but I'm having trouble finding a way to set it.

Comment: @avenmia  The `HttpContext` does not directly provide a `SetRouteData` method to modify route data. you need to manipulate the feature directly that handles routing data.

Comment: @avenmia i have modified the code. let me know if you still face any issue